# App Crash due to "UnKnown Error"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

My app crash without any Log write in Console. It gives me the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and stop.
Image for the error is as below:

[image]

**I didn't get any help to solve this problem.**

Comment: Error due to trying to access released memory. Possibly related to your UITableView

Comment: Are you adding or deleting rows to UITableView??

Comment: try this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 using this you can find where is it crashing.

Comment: Please show your code. So that only we can detect the problem

Comment: With the information you provide, do you think that we're able to help you to solve this problem ?

Comment: @MidhunMP, Thanks for your reply! I integrated "FourSquare API" & i don't know where it is add/delete the rows.

Comment: @satheeshwaran,Thanks for reply! I found my error where i try to insert the section in table view. Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you tried back tracing type bt in console after the crash see what it says

Answer (score 0):

As This is mainly due to When somewhere we try to access `deallocated` objects and if we enable `NSZombie` in project it show `Messages Sent To Deallocated Objects`. [so please to resolve this issue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-memory-allocations-help/Eliminating_Messages_To_Deallocated_Objects/06_Eliminating_Messages_To_Deallocated_Objects.html).
And you can run a dedicated `Zombies instrument`. Press `Command+I` to profile the app and select the `Zombies instrument`(with Simulatoe). If you get a `zombie`, you can display the entire memory history (each `retain/release`) For each and every object in your project

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of setting an environment variable on your executable (NSZombieEnabled = YES), and then running/debugging your app as normal. If you message a zombie, your app will crash/break to debugger and NSLog a message for you.

For more information, check out this [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).

and also check [this](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/).